# How to pass n number of props though a wrapper component with React Router v6

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router, react-props, auth0

I have tried:

`element: <ProtectedRoute component={ProjectBoard} prop1={prop1} prop2={prop2}/>`

I get the error Type '({ prop1, prop2 }: Props) => JSX.Element' is not assignable to type 'ComponentType<{}>'.

`element: <ProtectedRoute component={<ProjectBoard prop1={prop1} prop2={prop2}></ProjectBoard>}/>`

And then I get the error Type 'Element' is not assignable to type 'ComponentType<{}>'.

```
///// ProtectedRoute.tsx

interface ProtectedRouteProps {
  component: ComponentType;
}  

export const ProtectedRoute: React.FC<ProtectedRouteProps> = ({
  component,
  ...args
}) => {

  // HOC from Auth0, the component I want to pass props to is passed here
  const Component = withAuthenticationRequired(component, {
    onRedirecting: () => (
      <div></div>    
    ),
  })  
  
  return <Component {...args}></Component>;
}  

///// app,tsx

const myComponenet = (age: number) => {
  return <p>{age}</p>
}


// I want to pass in the props though my router here
const router = createBrowserRouter([
  {
    path: '/myComponent',
    element: <ProtectedRoute component={myComponenet} age={someState} />,
  }
])
```

I want to pass props into  and have them be passed to myComponent. Or some other way to get state from the current level into any component rendered by

Comment: `element: <ProtectedRoute component={ProjectBoard} prop1={prop1} prop2={prop2}/>` is the closest for the code you have, but it depends on how the `ProtectedRoute` component's props have been typed. What purpose really is your `ProtectedRoute` component providing that can't be attained by directly wrapping each routed component you want to inject "authentication required" props when exporting? The `ProtectedRoute` component should really be rendering an `Outlet`. Can you provide a more complete [mcve]?

Comment: @DrewReese I have tried to improve my example, could you check it? -About the outlet, are you saying it is better to just have any route I want to protect sent to an Outlet which is inside <ProtetedRoute>?

Comment: Is there an issue passing props to the component here `element: <ProtectedRoute component={myComponenet} age={someState} />`? What exactly is the problem? Just the proptypes declaration?

Comment: @DrewReese Yes that is the problem, it seems it can't be done like that. If "myComponents" has no props it will work, but if there are any props in myComponent I get the error ` Type '(age: number) => JSX.Element' is not assignable to type 'ComponentType<{}>'.` It seems to be a type error, but If I ignore the errors and load my app, the props don't seem to be actually getting passes at all.

Comment: @DrewReese EDIT: It's working fine now, but still with typescript errors, I guess just a type problem.

Comment: For starters, the `MyComponent` takes a props ***object***, not a number type, so the correct component typing would be `const MyComponenet = ({ age }: { age: number }) => { ... }`, but that still won't get past the `ProtectedRouteProps` interface as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ProtectedRouteProps` interface is missing the `age` prop, but more than this I don't think there's a straight forward way to type variadic props of unknown type and count.

However, I don't see much of a point to this `ProtectedRoute` component since it only decorates a component. You *should* decorate the components first and export the *decorated* component. From here you can set the routes configuration and pass the props directly to the components that need them.

Example:

MyComponent.tsx

```
interface MyComponentProps {
  age: number;
  // and any other props the component consumes
}

const MyComponent = ({ age }: MyComponentProps) => {
  return <p>{age}</p>
}

export default withAuthenticationRequired(MyComponent, {
  onRedirecting: () => (
    <div></div>    
  ),
});
```

App.tsx

```
import { createBrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import MyComponent from '../path/to/MyComponent';

const router = createBrowserRouter([
  ...
  {
    path: '/myComponent',
    element: <MyComponent age={someState} />, // <-- pass all the props necessary
  }
  ...
]);
```